# i'm forced to do composer update after each svn update

Tags: svn, laravel, composer-php

how to solve an issue, when several developers working on the same project using laravel framework have different local `laravel/vendor/composer/*` files?

imagine we have a production server, where we are not running composer anymore (or shall we?). to put all files to production, a developer must do the `composer update` locally, so laravel would dynamically create/change files such as those in the folder `vendor/composer/`. than developer commits those files to production and it works.

but after commit of my colleague, i want to update my `svn`. this means it will also update the dynamically created files, which will miss for example my current working changes. so i have to run composer update myself on my local instance to implement colleague's changes and also to have my current (still non-commited) changes included.

is this a normal good practice, to always run `composer update` on localhost after each svn update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many questions, but I think I understand what your issues are.

First of all make sure that you don't have the vendor directory version controlled.
Both composer.json and composer.lock should be under version control.

If someone has installed a new package via composer, all other developer should do a "composer install" after getting new code.

In production you **always** run "composer install", never "composer update".

"Composer update" should be ran in a controlled manner, because what that does is that it updates all packages with new versions (occording to composer.json settings).

Comment: ok, isnt running composer on production a security risk? as far as i know it - 1:downloads packages via pure http sometimes. 2:i would have to always manually check on production for downloaded vendor packages whether or not they contain malware (such as the repository itself could have been meanwhile compromised). i would rather to this check on my localhost prior and then put the checked vendor package files on production

Comment: and second, i want to know, whether this is a normal good practice for laravel framework, that each time a colleague does commit a new controller class, and i do update my repository, i have to run (although not always) `composer install` afterwards?

Comment: I don't think it should be considered a sequrity risk. If you do so, you need to manually upload the vendor directory but you should not have it in version control.

If you always do composer install you will get the same versions as you have locally, so you can review things in your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

> imagine we have a production server, where we are not running composer anymore (or shall we?).

You should be running the following on your production server to deploy new code:

```
php artisan down
git pull origin master
composer install
php artisan migrate
php artisan up
```

You should have 'composer.lock' included in your version control, so that all developers (and production server) are using the same version of /vendor files

> isnt running composer on production a security risk?

Absolutely not - it is standard practice to do this (assuming you have composer.lock). Composer.lock ensures that your server gets the exact same files. If you look inside composer.lock, you'll see items such as

```
"url": "https://api.github.com/repos/briannesbitt/Carbon/zipball/cde7a00d1410a17fb6d61b993cb017a78be1137c",
```

If a milcious person was to add a new version of the package, it would not have the same hashed zipball location - so you would still receive the correct version that you were expecting.

Comment: thx for your answer. can you advice on how to proceed with `subversion`? do all developers have to run `composer install` practically after each `svn update`?